# Animation in smartdiagram appearing simultaneously with math formulas in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a question about animations in the smartdiagram package in beamer.

I want the formulas to appear on side of the frame as the bubbles in the diagram appear.

Can this be done in beamer?

Here is the code for the smart diagram that I am using.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Diagram}


\smartdiagramset{planet size=2.7cm,
 planet text width=2.5cm,
 planet font= \normalsize,
 satellite size=1.9cm, 
 satellite text width=2.5cm,
 satellite font= \normalsize,
 distance planet-text=0,
 distance planet-satellite=3.7cm,
 /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<->}
 }



    \begin{center}
    \scalebox{0.8}{
            \usebeamercolor{background canvas}
        \smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{
            A,
           B,
            C,
            D,
            E,
            F
        }
    }
    \end{center}


\end{frame}
```

For example, as bubble $B$ appear I want $\cos(x)$ to appear, and as bubble $c$ appear I want $\sin(x)$ to appear.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{%
    planet size=2cm,
    planet text width=2cm,
    planet font= \normalsize,
    satellite size=1.5cm, 
    satellite text width=2cm,
    satellite font= \normalsize,
    distance planet-text=0,
    distance planet-satellite=3.2cm,
    /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<->}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{My Research Interests}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.8\textwidth}
        \usebeamercolor{background canvas}
        \smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{%
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D,
            E,
            F
        }
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \visible<1->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<2->{$\sin(x)$}

        \visible<3->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<4->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<5->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<6->{$\cos(x)$}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Edit:

This can be done even easier

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{%
    planet size=2cm,
    planet text width=2cm,
    planet font= \normalsize,
    satellite size=1.5cm, 
    satellite text width=2cm,
    satellite font= \normalsize,
    distance planet-text=0,
    distance planet-satellite=3.2cm,
    /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<->}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.8\textwidth}
        \usebeamercolor{background canvas}
        \smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{%
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D,
            E,
            F
        }
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        A\pause

            B\pause

            C\pause

            D\pause

            E\pause

            F
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Many Thanks.  I have one more question if you don't mind.  I know that to make formulas disappear we only have to specify the slide. That is instead of  \visible<2->  we can use  \visible<2>.   However,  what happens is that the formulas slide down. Can we make them stay at the same place?

Comment: @Lisa if you want to show only one formula per slide use `\only<2>{...}` instead of visible.

Comment: OK. One more question.   Can we have for one bubble appear two formulas, but the formulas appearing sequentially? For example, can a bubble appear, then formula, then another formula, then a bubble?

Comment: @Lisa not easily - better ask a new question about this.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Done. See here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418159/animation-in-smart-diagram-mixing-constellations-and-formulas-order-of-appearanc