# Animation in Smart Diagram Mixing Constellations and Formulas order of appearance

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram

This question is was raised in the previous post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418146/animation-in-smartdiagram-appearing-simultaneously-with-math-formulas-in-beamer/418149#418149).

The question is about doing animation in the smart diagram environment.

The question is whether we can mix the appears of formulas and bubble. For example, can we  do the following:

Buble A appears ->  formula (1) appears ->  formula (2) appears-> than Buble B appears.

The idea is that for a single bubble we might want to present several formulas and then move on to the next bubble.

In the following code, a single bubble and a single formula appear together.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{%
    planet size=2cm,
    planet text width=2cm,
    planet font= \normalsize,
    satellite size=1.5cm, 
    satellite text width=2cm,
    satellite font= \normalsize,
    distance planet-text=0,
    distance planet-satellite=3.2cm,
    /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<->}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.8\textwidth}
        \usebeamercolor{background canvas}
        \smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{%
            A,
            B,
            C,
            D,
            E,
            F
        }
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \visible<1->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<2->{$\sin(x)$}

        \visible<3->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<4->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<5->{$\cos(x)$}

        \visible<6->{$\cos(x)$}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To gain more fine control over the uncovering, you could manually draw the diagram:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.8\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, radius=1.2cm,minimum size=2.4cm,xshift=3.5cm,circle,text width=1cm,text centered]
            \node[fill=gray!30!white]       at (216:0.0) (A) {text text};
            \node<2->[fill=red!30!white]    at ( 72:3.2) (B) {B};
            \node<3->[fill=cyan!30!white]   at (144:3.2) (C) {C};
            \node<5->[fill=violet!30!white] at (216:3.2) (D) {D};
            \node<6->[fill=green!30!white]  at (288:3.2) (E) {E};
            \node<7->[fill=orange!30!white] at (  0:3.2) (F) {F};
            \draw<2->[latex-latex,ultra thick,red!30!white] (A) -- (B);
            \draw<3->[latex-latex,ultra thick,cyan!30!white] (A) -- (C);
            \draw<5->[latex-latex,ultra thick,violet!30!white] (A) -- (D);
            \draw<6->[latex-latex,ultra thick,green!30!white] (A) -- (E);
            \draw<7->[latex-latex,ultra thick,orange!30!white] (A) -- (F);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \visible<1->{A}

        \visible<2->{B}

        \visible<3->{C}

        \visible<4->{more C}

        \visible<5->{D}

        \visible<6->{E}

        \visible<6->{F}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to  write   instead of "A" in one of the bubbles  two words one on top of the other by bracking a line using "\\" but I couldn't. Can you suggest how to fix it?   It worked before. Can you suggest how to do it.

Comment: @Lisa Please see my updated code. Long text will automatically be split over multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. One more question. Is it possible in the second column to fix the initial position of A and everything to appear below without moving $A$ up? Right now things jump up and down.

Comment: @Lisa I don't get any jumping with the code from my answer

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Say you take A to be visible  from slide 1 to 3 (  \visible<1-3>{A} ) and be visible from 2  to 3  (\visible<2-3>{B})  and now C visible from 4 to 5 than ( \visible<3-5>{C}). Can we make C appear at the same hight that A appeared before?

Comment: @Lisa Same answer as yesterday: if you want to replace text, use `only`