# Error while displaying items in tikz with itemize

Tags: itemize, tikz-styles

I have my code below:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=magenta]{structure}
\date{}

% TYPING PACKAGES
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor,rotating,epic,eepic}

% ANIMATION AND GRAPHIC PACKAGES
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shapes.geometric,overlay-beamer-styles} % tikz library for node shapes...
%\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
%\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}



\newtheorem{bloc}{}
\newcommand{\ztu}{\psi}
\newtheorem{alertbloc}{}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
%\newcommand{\rouge}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
%\newcommand{\bleu}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
%\newcommand{\green}[1]{{\color{green}#1}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{sun/.style={rectangle,
                    color = black!70,
                    fill = black!15,
                    minimum size = 2.75cm,
                    inner sep = 0.1cm}}
\tikzset{satellite/.style={rectangle,
                    color = black!70,
                    minimum size = 1.8cm,
                    inner sep = 0.1cm}}
\tikzset{satellitearrow/.style={-latex,
                        line width = 0.125cm}}
\draw (0,0) node (frame) [shape=regular polygon, minimum size=7cm, rotate=-15] {};
\node (sun)         at (frame.center)   [sun]                                           {SUN};
\node (satellitea)  at (frame.corner 1) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=yellow!50] 
{{In 1974 J.Maynard. Smith},
{\begin{itemize}
  \item $x^{'}_1(t)=  x_1(t)[K_1-a_1 x_1(t)-b_{12}x_2(t)-\gamma_1x_1(t)x_2(t)]$
  \item $x^{'}_2(t) = x_1(t)[K_2-a_2 x_2(t)-b_{21}x_1(t)-\gamma_2x_1(t)x_2(t)]$
\end{itemize}}};



\node (satelliteb)  at (frame.corner 2) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=blue!50]  {B-STAR};
\node (satellitec)  at (frame.corner 3) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=green!50] {C-STAR};
\node (satellited)  at (frame.corner 4) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=red!50]   {D-STAR};
\node (satellitee)  at (frame.corner 5) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=orange!50]                     {E-STAR};
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=yellow!50]  (sun) -- (satellitea);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=blue!50]    (sun) -- (satelliteb);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=green!50]   (sun) -- (satellitec);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=red!50]     (sun) -- (satellited);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=orange!50]  (sun) -- (satellitee);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

And I want just to display a name for my method following by some equations followed by items but I got this error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.75 \end{frame}
```

So I'm kindly asking is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use something like `itemize` in a node, you need to use some option like `text width`. The following works but surely the output has some room for improvement. If you give me hint I may try to help you achieving a nicer output. One thing that is hard not to notice is that you are loading `smartdiagram` but not using it. Instead you are using and overwriting styles from this nice package  (satellite for instance).

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=magenta]{structure}
\date{}

% ANIMATION AND GRAPHIC PACKAGES
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shapes.geometric,overlay-beamer-styles} % tikz library for node shapes...
%\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\newtheorem{bloc}{}
\newcommand{\ztu}{\psi}
\newtheorem{alertbloc}{}
\beamersetuncovermixins{\opaqueness<1>{25}}{\opaqueness<2->{15}}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{sun/.style={rectangle,
                    color = black!70,
                    fill = black!15,
                    minimum size = 2.75cm,
                    inner sep = 0.1cm}}
\tikzset{satellite/.style={rectangle,
                    color = black!70,
                    minimum size = 1.8cm,
                    inner sep = 0.1cm}}
\tikzset{satellitearrow/.style={-latex,
                        line width = 0.125cm}}
\draw (0,0) node (frame) [shape=regular polygon, minimum size=7cm, rotate=-15] {};
\node (sun)         at (frame.center)   [sun]                                           {SUN};
\node (satellitea)  at (frame.corner 1) 
[satellite,anchor=west,xshift=-2.5cm, rectangle, inner sep=0cm,
fill=yellow!50,text width=7.5cm] 
{{In 1974 J.Maynard. Smith},
{\begin{itemize}
  \item $x^{'}_1(t)=  x_1(t)[K_1-a_1 x_1(t)-b_{12}x_2(t)-\gamma_1x_1(t)x_2(t)]$
  \item $x^{'}_2(t) = x_1(t)[K_2-a_2 x_2(t)-b_{21}x_1(t)-\gamma_2x_1(t)x_2(t)]$
\end{itemize}}};
\node (satelliteb)  at (frame.corner 2) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=blue!50]  {B-STAR};
\node (satellitec)  at (frame.corner 3) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=green!50] {C-STAR};
\node (satellited)  at (frame.corner 4) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=red!50]   {D-STAR};
\node (satellitee)  at (frame.corner 5) [satellite, rectangle, inner sep=0cm, fill=orange!50]                     {E-STAR};
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=yellow!50]  (sun) -- (satellitea);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=blue!50]    (sun) -- (satelliteb);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=green!50]   (sun) -- (satellitec);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=red!50]     (sun) -- (satellited);
\draw [satellitearrow, draw=orange!50]  (sun) -- (satellitee);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make use of `smartdiagram`, you could (again) "hack" it (some elements here are from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418159/121799)).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{%
    planet size=2cm,
    planet text width=2cm,
    planet font= \normalsize,
    satellite size=1.5cm, 
    satellite text width=2cm,
    satellite font= \normalsize,
    distance planet-text=0,
    distance planet-satellite=3.2cm,
    /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<->}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\begingroup%<- keep hacks local
\tikzset{satellite/.append style={/utils/exec={\ifnum\xi=2
\pgfkeysalso{shape=rectangle,text width=8.5cm,xshift=2cm,font=\small}
\else
\ifnum\xi<5
\pgfkeysalso{shape=rectangle}
\fi
\fi}}}
\smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{%
            Sun,
            {In 1974 J.Maynard. Smith
\begin{itemize}
  \item $x^{'}_1(t)=  x_1(t)[K_1-a_1 x_1(t)-b_{12}x_2(t)-\gamma_1x_1(t)x_2(t)]$
  \item $x^{'}_2(t) = x_1(t)[K_2-a_2 x_2(t)-b_{21}x_1(t)-\gamma_2x_1(t)x_2(t)]$
\end{itemize}},
            Sat B,
            Sat C,
            Sat D,
            Sat E
}\endgroup
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Back to normal}
\smartdiagramanimated[constellation diagram]{%
            Sun,
            Sat A,
            Sat B,
            Sat C,
            Sat D,
            Sat E
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if all the satellites are bulky, you could use e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418170/121799) as starting point for an animated version.

Comment: Thank you again!! for your previous help as well!! regarding some hints, I don't know what you need to achieve this :\ about the second thing you asked regarding smartdiagram I'm just split this frame to just test it seperatly and I took it from a document where I used smartdiagram together with tikz but I have another issue if you coud help me with it again, is there anyway to make this tikz animated like smartdiagramanimated in smartdiagram library?

Comment: @HamzaHsn One thing you always can do is to work with `visible on`, which comes with the `overlay-beamer-styles` library that you already load. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418170/121799 for an explicit answer. You could also use an animated constellation diagram as in the corresponding question.

Comment: ok I'll try to use it :) any way, thank you so much! you're my savior today ;)

Comment: I already voted ;) but I'm wondering, I have other smartdiagrams, so with your second solution, isn't gonna apply on all the smart diagrams in my document? despite that I want to keep them as they are now and just use this

Comment: @HamzaHsn I used `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` precisely in order to keep these hacks local, i.e. not to affect the other diagrams.

Comment: Ah now I understand, but with your second solution with smartdiagram, I could not use the rectangle only in the one which you specified, so how I can manage to specify it in others and others keeps with circles? :)

Comment: No I didn't, maybe I wasn't clear, so I'll try again, I want my "Sat B" "Sat C" in a rectangle shape and not in a circle, I hope I was clear

Comment: @HamzaHsn I added a version with more rectangles. You need to add further `\ifnum` statements, `\xi=1` is the planet, `\xi=2` satellite A and so on.

Comment: Thanks! now I got it :)